# How to set "mail from" and "envelope from" in Java (version 1.7)

Tags: java, email

I tried that send mail in Java.

- OS X
- use version 1.7

My customer used contact form.

My Customer hope that change "mail from".
It is "user email" that sent from "contact form". (This is spoofing mail. But, no problem. Because send from customer server to customer mail server.)

But, I have no idea that set envelope from in java.

I tried java code below.

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

private static void sendMail() throws Exception {
    String smtpServer  = "hogehoge.smtp.server.com";
    int port           = "587";
    String userid      = "from@gmail.com";
    String password    = "password";
    String contentType = "text/plain";
    String subject     = "Test Subject";
    String from        = "from@gmail.com";
    String to          = "to@gmail.com";
    String bounceAddr  = "from@gmail.com";
    String body        = "send mail";

    Properties props   = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
    props.put("mail.smtp.from", bounceAddr);

    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContent(body, contentType);

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    try{
        System.out.println("Sending ....");
        transport.connect(smtpServer, port, userid, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        System.out.println("Sending done ...");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error Sending: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    transport.close();
}
```

I think it is usually code.

But, I got error.

> 503 not your domain (#5.5.1)

Probably set "mail from" that not register email address from customer mail server.

So, I tried telnet too that use terminal.

```
$ printf "%s\0%s\0%s" from@gmail.com from@gmail.com password | openssl base64 -e | tr -d '\n'; echo
ZnJvbUBnbWFpbC5jb20AZnJvbUBnbWFpbC5jb20AcGFzc3dvcmQ=

$ telnet hogehoge.smtp.server.com 587
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to hogehoge.smtp.server.com
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.server.com ESMTP
EHLO localhost // my type

250-smtp.server.com
...
250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
AUTH PLAIN ZnJvbUBnbWFpbC5jb20AZnJvbUBnbWFpbC5jb20AcGFzc3dvcmQ= // my type
235 ok, go ahead (#2.0.0)

MAIL FROM:<from@gmail.com> // my type
250 ok

RCPT TO:<to@gmail.com> // my type
250 ok

DATA // my type
354 go ahead

subject:Test Mail                 // my type
from:User Mail <spoof@gmail.com>  // my type. set envelope from mail address.
to:to@gmail.com                   // my type
                                  // my type
send mail.                        // my type
.                                 // my type
250 ok 1481706367 qp 12070

quit // my type
221 smtp.server.com
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This is successed.

How to set envelope from in java that like case telnet above.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I believe `mail.smtp.from` is the envelope `MAIL FROM`

Comment: It could be something about the IP address / hostname you are using.  In the telnet experiment, you used localhost.  A mail server is liable to trust  connection from `127.0.0.1` / `localhost` to spoof the sender more than an off-host IP address.

Comment: Can you please try; message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@xxx.com", "No Reply"));  and  message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no-reply@xxx.com"));

Comment: Thank you for comment! I gonna try it, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for comments. I was solved that problem.

I was cording that mail server login id string at `mail.smtp.from`.

And,  I was written that spoofing string at  `from` of `message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));`.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.from", ADMINI_MAIL_ADDRESS); // mail server login id.
```

and

```
message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from)); // spoofing mail address string.
```

Thank you for everyone!